# How to conduct a query in another scene layer in a webscene?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, web-scene

I have the following situation,

I have imported a web scene into a script. The webscene consist of **two scene layers** and during most of the script I am only working with one scene layer. However almost at the end of my script, whenever I want to click on an anchor element in a list in the sidebar which I have created with HTML, I would like to zoom in on an object in another scene layer.

The anchor element does contain a dataset.gebouwid and I include this information in a new Query. However now I am completely lost in which way I can use this query to query through another sceneLayer.

I have looked at the sandbox of [Query SceneLayerView](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/layers-scenelayerview-query/index.html), however in this specific case throughout the whole script there appears only one scene Layer. So I was wondering what in case when you want to query through another scene Layer.

```
 for (i = 0; i < uniqueItems.length; i++) {
                                var value2 = uniqueItems[i];
                                var subtext = value2.substring(value2.length - 9, value2.length);
                                //   console.log(subtext);

                                var entry = document.createElement('li');
                                var link = document.createElement('a');
                                link.textContent = value2;
                                // link.href=value2;
                                link.href = '#';
                                link.dataset.gebouwid = subtext;
                                // console.log(subtext);
                                link.onclick = function (event) {
                                    var clickedElement = event.target;
                                    var element = clickedElement.dataset.gebouwid;

                                    var query = new Query({
                                        where: "lokaalid = '" + element + "'",
                                        returnGeometry: true,
                                        outFields: ["*"]
                                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In the sample you mentioned the scene layer is retrieved using `webScene.layers.getItemAt(0)`

Assuming you are accessing the scene layer the same way in your code, you can access any other layer by increasing the index in [`getItemAt(index)`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-Map.html#layers):

```
var sceneLayer = webScene.layers.getItemAt(1);
```

An alternative, more robust way of retrieving specific layers in a web scene is using its title instead of an index:

```
var sceneLayer = webScene.layers.find(function(layer){
  return layer.id === "[Replace with title of 2nd scene layer]";
});
```